# Contention error 1 or 0?

Tags: digital-logic, error

[image: A circuit]

why these AND gates are getting no output. I confirmed all the connections. The first and gate is getting 0 and 1 as an input but there is an error in output. Can someone help? Urgent

Comment: B input goes directly to input of c OR gate. That must do it. ensure V+,0V are all. Connected. there’s no contention just a missing connection

Comment: You can ask yourself is it OK to connect logic gate outputs together.

Comment: Is this homework or are you in an exam? "Urgent" is your problem, not ours.